# C# Simple Type w/ Generic Type

Tags: c#, types, switch-statement

I want to do different things with a generic type given that it is a byte array, int, etc.

```
    public void GenericType<T>(T Input)
    {
        switch (typeof(T))
        {
            case (typeof(byte[])):
                break;
            case (typeof(int)):
            case (typeof(float)):
            case (typeof(long)):
                break;
            case (typeof(string)):
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Type Incompatability Error");
                break;
        }
    }

Sandbox.cs(12,13): error CS0151: A switch expression of type `System.Type' cannot be converted to an integral type, bool, char, string, enum or nullable type
```

add:

My specific case has some code that is generic and some code that is specific. I also have one where I do not actually pass a T variable. Solutions thus far work if there is a variable.

```
    public void GenericType<T>()
```

Not being terribly experienced, what is the best practice in C#?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot make a switch with evey variable type, thus the error. You can use a switch with bool, char, string, enum or nullable type. Use if statements

Comment: are you sure this method needs to be generic?  the implementation doesn't look generic at all.

Comment: The best practice is not to use generic methods that are not really generic. If you need to to different things based on the type then overloads are more type-safe.

Comment: It's going to be easier to tolerate the code duplication than the hassle of using templates with System.Type comparing Simple Type for the cases where there is no variable initiated, because I am in this catch-22 where it needs to be initiated at some point to know what to do with it, which means it cannot be generic.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `switch` using [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching):

```
switch(Input)
{
   case int i:
      // do something with i
   case string x:
      // do something with x
}
```

Comment: Note that this is only available in C# 7 and above.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like

```
if (Input is int i) { DoSomething(i) ; }
else if (Input is long l) { DoSomething(l) ; }
```

Best?  Maybe.  Works? Yup.

You are effectively calling `System.Object` GenericType in this example.